# Behaviour of ++ operator in a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an array of structs, and I made a pointer to the first element in the struct. I have seen the `++` operator being used in my code on the pointer, like this: `ptrStruct++`, what does this exactly do? Go to the next array position? Or it is used as an operator overloading?

Code here, and the objects are from Ogre3D:

```
RGBA colours[nVertices];
RGBA *pColour = colours;
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(1.0,0.0,0.0), pColour++); //0 colour
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(1.0,1.0,0.0), pColour++); //1 colour
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(0.0,1.0,0.0), pColour++); //2 colour
```

Comment: You got it, go to the next array position. ++ always does this on pointers, you cannot overload ++ for a pointer.

Comment: It will increment to the next memory address contained in the array. Effectively, `address + sizeof(array[0])`.

Comment: @Yuushi I think that's worthy of an answer I'd upvote.

Comment: @Yuushi Thanks! Post it as an answer and I will select as valid if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`++`, when applied to a pointer, advances said pointer to the next *item.* It does this by scaling based on the size of the item being pointed to.

So, if you have a `char *pc` pointing at location `0x1000`, `pc++` will advance it to the next `char`, or `0x1001`. However, an `int *pi` (assuming `sizeof (int)` is `4`) would advance from location `0x1000` to `0x1004`.

This is not something you normally need to worry about unless you're casting between different pointers. Suffice to say that:

```
RGBA colours[nVertices];
RGBA *pColour = colours;    // same as &(colours[0])
pColour++;                  //     now &(colours[1])
```

will simply advance `pColour` to point to `colours[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ptrStruct++
```

The pointer steps forward and points to the next element in the array. Compiler knows the size of each element in the array then each `++` advances the pointer in the memory according to that size.

```
RGBA colours[nVertices];  // Assume `sizeof(RGBA)` is 4bytes
RGBA *pColour = colours;

      sizeof(a[0])                                 
     <------------>                                
     +------------+------------+-------------+--------
     |            |            |             |     
     |   4bytes   |   4bytes   |   4bytes    |  4by...   
     |            |            |             |     
     +------------+------------+-------------+--------
     ^            ^                                
     |            |                                
   before       after++ 
   pColour      pColour
```

As a pointer to a `RGBA` with size 4, each `++` says to compiler, advance forward 4 bytes. In other words, the length of a single step  is 4 bytes.

Also, you can rewrite the code as below:

```
RGBA colours[nVertices];
int i = 0;
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(1.0,0.0,0.0), colours[i++]);
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(1.0,1.0,0.0), colours[i++]);
rs->convertColourValue(ColourValue(0.0,1.0,0.0), colours[i++]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It will increment to the next memory address contained in the array. Effectively, `address + sizeof(array[0]).` This will work for any (complete) type.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the pointer as

```
RGBA *pColour = colours;
```

So doing pclour++ means  pcolour + sizeof(RGBA)

Answer (score 0):

It will advance to the next item in the list. I would leave this as a comment but I can't yet.

Comment: I know this, but I was asking about the exact behavior. Is is part of C++ or is it implemented as operator overloading? Can it be used with every datatype?

Comment: @Pacha: The behavior of `++` on pointers is built into the definition of the language (the C++ standard). However, for the purposes of operator overload resolution, C++ standard 13.6 defines "candidate operator functions" of a specific form that resembles user-defined operator overloads. They are of course don't exist as actual code in any file.

Comment: This is simply a basic arithmetic operation. A pointer is simply an address which is a (these days, generally) a 32 or 64 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

ptrStruct++ will make ptrStruct to point next struct in the array.